# How to convert string to associative array

Tags: php

Let's say i have this string :

```
$myString = 'var1=test1&var2=test2';
```

I just want to convert $myString to am associative array , so the result would be :

```
myArray['var1'] = 'test1';
myArray['var2'] = 'test2';
```

I tried explode, but it will create a numerated array like this :

```
myArray = explode('&',$myString);
// result would be $myArray[0] = 'var1=test' and so on, not what i want
```

Is there an easy way to do this, besides manually doing this programatically by iterating on the $myString using a for loop ?

Comment: Not at all. Use [parse_str()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str).

Comment: @MarkusZeller Thank you , it worked ! SO is so toxic nowadays, i don't understand why would people negative my post , it's just an objective question with a simple answer. Thanks again, you can post as answer so i can accept it.

Comment: I +1'd to even out the post rating. Great Post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `parse_str()` function parses a string into variables. Read more about it at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Use the following code:

```
<?php
$myString = 'var1=test1&var2=test2';

parse_str($myString, $myArray);

print_r($myArray);
```

The output will be

```
Array
(
    [var1] => test1
    [var2] => test2
)
```